# What are the benefits of encrypting a web config file with a certificate?

Tags: windows, iis, encryption, web-config, config

What are the benefits of encrypting a web config with a certificate and what type of attack does it help prevent as opposed to other encryption methods?

It's my understanding that encrypting the web config will become useful if an attacker gains access to a web server or if you serve the config as a static file but what is preventing them from running "aspnet_regiis -pdf" on the server to get the plaintext contents?

Comment: If someone can run code on your server, all bets are off.  Encrypting can help protect against attackers who can access your server's disk or a backup thereof.

Comment: BTW, I’m unsure that web.config encryption can be used with IIS’s use of web.config - so only the ASP.NET-specific parts can be encrypted.

Comment: It depends on how you encrypt the file and how that certificate is protected (certificate private key has access control). Even if a hacker gains access to your machine, initially he/she might not be able to be an administrator there, so might not be able to decrypt everything. That can delay the hacking process and give you some time to detect the invasion and fight back.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://security.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable a place.